# Can a view be used as a source for creating other views in databases?

Tags: sql, database

Is it a bad practice to create a view from another view? Why or why not?

I want to create a view V1 that will be a subset of a table T1 by restricting values of a column in the table to distinct values of another existing view V2.

I want to know if this is good practice or should I use the base table used to create V2 to achieve this and not use V2?

Comment: In my opinion, building the new view on the existing one is usually even the better approach. After all, you built the existing view to reduce complexity from writing queries. So building the new view on this is what it is made for; the new view will be easier to write and read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Of course...

```
CREATE VIEW V1
AS 
   SELECT 1 AS N
GO

CREATE VIEW V2
AS 
   SELECT N+1 AS M
   FROM V1
GO
```

This example si for Microsoft SQL Server...

Of course it is a good practice to massively use views instead of table...